# Markline connect to label echarts

Tags: javascript, typescript, charts

I'm trying to create a line to connect the respective stacked bar into label, is there any possibility in echarts javascript? I tried the markline parameter but it didn't fit very well, and I don't know if there is other parameter that can help in this case. Any tips about this?

```
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    show: false,
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    data: ['Sun'],
    show: false,
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: '0 products',
      type: 'bar',
      roundCap: true,
      color: '#37B04B',
      stack: 'total',
      label: {
        formatter: '{icon|✔}      {c|{c}} {d|%} ',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderColor: '#37B04B',
        show: true,
        position: 'right',
        distance: 70,
        rich: {
          c: {
            color: '#37B04B',
            fontSize: 28,
          },
        }
      },
      data: [3200]
    },
    {
      name: '3+ products',
      type: 'bar',
      barWidth: 70,
      color: '#C51F2A',
      itemStyle: {
        emphasis: {
          barBorderRadius: [50, 50]
        },
        normal: {
          barBorderRadius: [50, 50, 0, 0],
        },
      },
      stack: 'total',
      label: {
        formatter: '{icon|✘} {c|{c}} {d|%} ',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderColor: 'red',
        show: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 30,
        padding: [10, 5],
        position: 'right',
        distance: 70,
        rich: {
          c: {
            color: 'red',
            fontSize: 16
          },
        }
      },
      data: [500]
    }
  ]
};
```